# Sophisticated square cells table

Tags: tables

Is it possible to draw tables as those in Figures below. Tables should have square cells and notations along borders.

I know that I could use the TAB environment from the Easytable package to create square cells tables, but I do not know how to put notations over the top border. I would like to use the multicolumn command for Figure 2 but it does not work in the TAB environment. Or maybe there is another simple approach to achieve the same?

There is and alternative to TAB from the Easytable package as suggested by this link http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2005-2/robertson/, but I cannot insert any notations and the command multicolumn does not work. I use XeLaTeX.

[image: Table with square cells and notations along vertical and horizontal border.]

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this. You say that the tables should have square cells but figure 2 does not satisfy this condition. Is the problem that it does not have square cells? Or are square cells not really the point?

Answer (score 4):

**Solution Ideas**

The solution provided here is without any package or anything like that. I strongly suggest that you go for such solutions before you start using any
package. You should know what you are doing.

*(See the end of this post for a solution which uses the square cell technique
from [your provided link](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2005-2/robertson/).)*

1. Your first table actually contains four columns, one with a rule at its
   right, then three ruled ones.
2. The notations along borders are actually part of the table. Special type
   of cells are used here. See the next two enumerations.
3. For the notations at the top, you use `\multicolumn`. The cells span one
   column, have centered contents and are without borders (`\multicolumn{1}{c}`). We
   define a macro (`\mca`) since we use them a number of times.
4. For notations at the left, again you use `\multicolumn`. The cells span one
   column, have centered contents, with border at right (`\multicolumn{1}{c|}`). Again, we
   define a macro (`\mcb`) since we use them a number of times.
5. You use `\cline` to span a horizontal line from column 2 to column 4 in the first table.
6. The second table is a simpler one with three columns. We reuse the macro `\mca` for this one as well.
7. You tweak `\arraystretch` to adjust row heights (to get the square cells
   as asked by you).

I am pretty sure that you know how to put these tables inside [float environments](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions).

---

**The Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\mca#1{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\def\mcb#1{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.25}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|}
  \mca{}  & \mca1 & \mca2 & \mca3 \\\cline{2-4}
  \mcb1   & AB    & BC    & DA    \\\cline{2-4}
  \mcb2   & EF    & GH    & IJ    \\\cline{2-4}
  \mcb{C} & KL    & MN    & OP    \\\cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \mca{3 bit} & \mca{1-2 bits} & \mca{0 bit} \\\hline
  1           & 10             & 1           \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

**The Output**

[image]

**Solution Using [Your Provided Link](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2005-2/robertson/)**

If you insist on using the technique from your provided link, here is an alternate  solution for the first table. This uses the square cell technique
from the link.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}

\newlength\celldim
\setlength\celldim{3em}
\newlength\fontheight
\settoheight\fontheight{A}
\newlength\extraheight
\setlength\extraheight{\celldim - \fontheight}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{S}
{ @{}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}
p{\celldim}
<{\rule[-0.5\extraheight]{0pt}%
{\fontheight + \extraheight}}
@{} }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\mca#1{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\def\mcb#1{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}}
\begin{tabular}{c|S|S|S|}
  \mca{}  & \mca1 & \mca2 & \mca3 \\\cline{2-4}
  \mcb1   & AB    & BC    & DA    \\\cline{2-4}
  \mcb2   & EF    & GH    & IJ    \\\cline{2-4}
  \mcb{C} & KL    & MN    & OP    \\\cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Second Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can nest the tabular environments. All cells are 2cm x 2cm:

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\newcommand\ML[1]{\llap{#1\quad}}

\begin{document}

\huge
\begin{tabular}{c}
\begin{TAB}(e,2cm,2cm){ccc}{ccc}   
     1 & 2 & 3 
\end{TAB}\\[-\normalbaselineskip]
\begin{TAB}(e,2cm,2cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}   
\ML{1}AB & BC & DA    \\
\ML{2}EF & GH & IJ    \\
\ML{C}KL & MN & OP    \\
\end{TAB}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]